# Solving recurrence relation of algorithm complexity?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Supposing I write an algorithm that results into this kind of recurrence relation

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
T(0)=T(1)=1 \\
T(n)=T\left(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \right)+T\left(\lceil n/2 \rceil\right)+c_1n+c_2
\end{array}
\right.$$

This kind of algorithm looks like it is of $O(n\log(n))$ but how can I solve this recurrence relation to find its complexity?

Comment: can you continue it  and  express $T(n/2)$  left part i meant

Comment: i don't get what you're saying.

Comment: You could verify it for 2-powers first and then try to reduce the general case to this special case.

Comment: @HansGiebenrath great idea! thanks